# Create a custom Price tabel

Tags: object, salesforce

I need some help building a price table on Salesforce

I have a custom object call request,where the user selects a type and a subtype from a picklist and i need to show him different prices according to is selection.

I can t do everything in code with "if/else", because the list is extensive and the user may want to change a price..

Do you have any tips, i would like to do something like a price tabel and then have code to read the values...

Thanks in advance
(sorry for the english)

Comment: We'd need a lot more context here. What technologies are you using?

Comment: I m using Salesforce!